# C++ Qt memory allocation exception with QList

Tags: c++, qt, exception, memory, qlist

How can this ever happen that this throws an exception

```
    for(int h = 0 ; h < listOne.count() ; ++h) {
        delete[] listOne[h];
    }
```

with QList listOne ? I delete float* arrays iterating until I reach number of element in the QList ...

**EDIT & SOLUTION**

In fact, it fails when I am adding only one float in one item of QList. Then, it is no more a `float*` and you cannot `delete []` it.

Comment: Show where you add elements to the QList.

Comment: show listOne declaration.

Comment: The question is why to use c-style arrays instead of e.g. QVector/std::vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
How can this ever happen that this throws an exception
```

One posibility: you added one array 2 time to the list. 
One fix:

```
for(int h = 0 ; h < listOne.count() ; ++h) {
    delete[] listOne[h];
    listOne[h]=nullptr;
}
```

Maybe others errors (you added not-array pointers to the list).

EDIT:

> In fact, it fails when I am adding only one float in one item of
>   QList. Then, it is no more a float* and you cannot delete [] it.

I suspected...
A very simple fix:

```
float *pi=new float[1];
pi[0]=3.14f;
```

Now add `pi` to the list